# Query Select and Show All First Table And Second Table Even is not Exist in Second Table

Tags: php, mysql

SAMPLE TABLE

TABLE FIRST_TABLE

```
| rid | requirements |
|  1  |    2x2  pic  |
|  2  |   valid id   |
|  3  |   137 form   |
|  4  |   app form   |
```

Second table

```
| id | applicant_id | rid | remarks |
|  1 |      1       |  1  |  pass   |
|  2 |      1       |  2  |  pass   |
|  3 |      2       |  1  |  pass   |
```

How to select all records from first table and show even the data is not exist on second table.
Result should be like this.

```
applicant_id | rid | remarks |
     1       |  1  |  pass   |
     1       |  2  |  pass   |
     1       |  3  |  null   | 
     1       |  4  |  null   |
```

this is my sample code.

```
select requirements from first_table
left join second_table on first_table.rid = second_table.rid
where second_table.applicant_id = 1
group by first_table.rid

//result : 
 applicant_id | rid | remarks |
     1        |  1  |  pass   |
     1        |  2  |  pass   |
```

Comment: `select requirements` certainly can't produce a result containing `applicant_id | rid | remarks`. Can you include the actual code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to move the second_table.applicant_id = 1 to the join.

```
select requirements, first_table.rid, remarks
from first_table
left join second_table on 
  first_table.rid = second_table.rid and 
  second_table.applicant_id = 1
group by first_table.rid
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a0cffdd/17

Comment: thanks you save my day! I didn't know i need to move second table applicant id to the join, thanks again!